# approximate Poisson disk / blue noise sampling

Tags: random-number-generation

*Poisson disk* or *blue noise* sampling consists of finding a random, maximal set of points $\{x_i\}$ in a domain $\Omega$ such that $\|x_i - x_j\| \ge r$ for some fixed radius $r$ and for all $i$, $j$.
There are several algorithms for efficient blue noise sampling, for example [Bridson's algorithm](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Erbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf).
Blue noise sampling is used in many fields, including computer graphics and mesh improvement.

Many papers use the empirical [periodogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodogram) for evaluating the quality of the resulting blue noise samples.
This got me thinking:
**Is there any published work on generating *approximate* blue noise samples through Fourier inversion of the ideal periodogram?**
The resulting samples might have some pairs $x_i$, $x_j$ of points such that $\|x_i - x_j\| < r$.
But strict adherence to this exclusion condition isn't necessarily a hard requirement for a lot of the things people use blue noise for.
My hunch is that some kind of Fourier or spectral-based approach might (1) make better use of fast DFT algorithms, instead of spending all its time traversing a bunch of linked lists, and (2) be implementable in a single laptop screen of code at 12-point font.
Bridson's algorithm fails on both counts.

I found [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICASSP.2016.7472145) which is kind of in the right direction -- they calculate that the power spectral density of blue noise is

$$P(k) = 1 - \rho\left(\frac{2\pi r}{k}\right)^{\frac{d}{2}}J_{d/2}(kr)$$

for samples of density $\rho$ in dimension $d$, where $J_\nu$ are the Bessel functions of the first kind.
But this is used more as a means to evaluate algorithms rather than the basis for an algorithm as such.

Comment: The issue is that inverting an arbitrary perdiogram doesn't have to produce points. Note that this can be used in the optimization however. E.g. if you want to optimize wrt a kernel $g$ then you typically want to minimize $\|g * \sum_k \delta(x-x_k)\|^2_2$ you can rewrite this objective function in the Fourier domain as $| \mathcal{F}[g]|^2 \odot |\sum_k \mathcal{F}[\delta(x-x_k)]|^2$ (this is due to Parseval's identity and properties of complex number magnitudes and multiplication).

Comment: I noticed I missed a sum over the indices of the latter, what I wrote gives you an image.